# Can both esc key and escape sequences be separtely detected on Unix systems?

Tags: ruby, input, terminal, escaping

I have a Linux distribution, and I'd like to be able to detects a wide range of keys, but I can't figure out how to distinguish the press of the Escape key, versus a key detected as keypress.

If I use this:

```
require 'io/console'
puts STDIN.raw { STDIN.getc }
```

and press, say, `Arrow up`, the interpreter will return immediately `\e`, then on subsequent `getc` calls, without pressing any key, it will return the remaining chars of the escape sequence (`[` and `A`).

The problem is that, after the first `getc` call, I don't know if the user has actually pressed `Esc`, or another key which generates an escape sequence.

Is it possible to make the distinction between the two cases, without multiple `getc` invocations?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, because the character input is done at a higher level than the physical keyboard. That is, *by design*, an `ESC` character read by `getc` is an `ESC` character, no matter how on the keyboard it was input (or not input on the keyboard at all, for example, by redirection).

I don't think Ruby out of the box has a way to detect hardware events such as keyboard presses. There is `IOCTL` for lower level device access, but I don't know how to use it for your purpose. But even if you could, how would you handle alternate keyboard layouts? What you expect to be an `ESC` key might be mapped to a different character.

There is a `read_nonblock` method on `$stdin` that you might use to see if there is an additional character in the buffer immediately after reading the `ESC` key. If so, it's likely that a special character other than `ESC` was pressed. If not, it's likely the `ESC` key was pressed.